# Excel - automate daily task of saving a copy and refreshing external connection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am curious if anyone knows how the following could be accomplished.

We have a daily excel workbook that is refreshed every morning with a number of external connection reports. The data that is reported needs to be saved every day for audit purposes so a new file is copied before refreshing the data.

What I am hoping to automate is:

1. Save a copy of the file with the file name of current day's date and specific text (same text every day)
2. Refresh external connections on the latest excel file saved while keeping all previous days files static

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can probably be done with VBA. I suggest you try your hand at it and if you have a more specific problem, come back and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can come close with the Windows Command Prompt

1) Launch a Windows script with opens and Excel File Template

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE C:\USERS\username\DAILY.XLTX
```

(or DAILY.XLSM if it contains macros &/or scripts)

2) Refresh your connections
3) Save the Excel file with a default name such as DAILY.XLSX
4) Exit from Excel
5) Upon exit, script renames the saved file to DAILY_20191111.XLSX

```
REN DAILY.XLSX DAILY_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~3,2%.XLSX
```